# Sufficient condition on variance of RV for solution to equation

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, probability-inequalities

Let $\tilde{\theta}$ be a non-negative random variable drawn from a twice continuously differentiable CDF $F(\theta) := \Pr\{\tilde{\theta} \leq \theta\}$ over the support $[0, \overline{\theta}]$, with $F'(\theta) > 0$ for all $\theta \in (0,\overline{\theta})$. It further holds that $\mathbb{E}(\tilde{\theta}) = 1$ (such that necessarily $\overline{\theta} > 1$).

I am looking for a *sufficient* condition on the variance $\sigma^2$ of $\tilde{\theta}$ such that the equation

$h(\theta) := A + B\cdot F(\theta) - \theta F'(\theta) = 0$,

where $A, B > 0$, permits at least one solution.

Note that $h(0) = A > 0$. Hence, by continuity it suffices to show that there exists some $\theta > 0$ such that $h(\theta) < 0$.

My current approach is as follows:

From Chebyshev's inequality, it is known that for $z < 1$, at least $1-\frac{\sigma^2}{z^2}$ of $\tilde{\theta}$'s probability mass must fall in the range $[1-z, 1+z]$. Therefore, the average probability density in this range is at least given by $\frac{1-\frac{\sigma^2}{z^2}}{2z}$. Then clearly, $\max_{\theta \in [1-z,1+z]} \theta F'(\theta) \geq (1-z)\frac{1-\frac{\sigma^2}{z^2}}{2z}$. One can now look for the optimal $z$ which maximizes this expression. Call this $z^*$.

At the same time, $A + B\cdot F(\theta)$ is clearly bounded above by $A + B$.

Hence, it is sufficient to find $\sigma^2$ such that $A + B - (1-z^*)\frac{1-\frac{\sigma^2}{(z^*)^2}}{2z^*} < 0$, which can be solved for $\sigma^2$.

The problem is that my sufficient condition on the variance of $\tilde{\theta}$ is far from being sharp. Numerical simulations show that it is often more than an ordner of magnitude below the sufficient variance for common probability distributions. Since I took many shortcuts, I am wondering whether (much) sharper conditions can be given. Any input is appreciated - many thanks in advance!

---

EDIT:

I have the feeling that the following might constitute a tight sufficient bound for the problem:

$Var(\tilde{\theta}) \leq \frac{1}{(A+B)(2+A+B)}$. This bound is indeed tight for $F(\theta) = \left(\frac{\gamma \theta}{\gamma+1}\right)^{\gamma}$, $\gamma > 0$, which is defined over the support $[0, \frac{\gamma+1}{\gamma}]$, has a mean of $1$, and a variance of $\frac{1}{\gamma(2+\gamma)}$. At least I could not find any counterexamples, i.e., permissible CDFs with a lower variance for which there is no solution to $h(\theta) = 0$. Of course, they might very well exist, and even if my conjecture is correct, I don't really see how I could prove it. Has anybody got an idea?

Comment: Various necessary bounds on the values of $A$ and $B$ arise. Are we to assume that these hold?

Comment: Other than $A, B > 0$, I don't put any structure on them. Could you perhaps elaborate on this?

Comment: The bound that you derived for example leads to an upper bound for the variance that, since the variance must be strictly positive, places a necessary upper bound on $A+B$ in terms of $z^*$. By the way, your bound necessarily requires also $\sigma^2 < (z^*)^2$. Is this indeed loose?

Comment: Thanks, I now see your point. For example, if we forget for a moment about the maximization with respect to $z$, we could set e.g. $z = 1/2$ (as you correctly pointed out, this then also requires that $\sigma^2 < (1/2)^2$). Then I get $\theta F'(\theta) \geq 1/2 - 2\sigma^2$, such that $A + B - (1/2 - 2\sigma^2) < 0$ leads to the bound $\sigma^2 < 1/4 - (A+B)/2$, which is only feasible if $A + B < 1/2$. Ideally, I would like to get rid of such restrictions. My intuition is as follows: If the variance of $\tilde{\theta}$ is very low, then its density should be very high [to be continued...]

Comment: ... close to its mean of $1$. But then, for any $A$ and $B$, there should be a $\theta$ for which $A + B\cdot F(\theta) - \theta F'(\theta) < 0$, implying that there must be a solution to the original equation.

Comment: I think the maximization with respect to $z$ is crucial. Carrying out the full calculation, the sufficient condition becomes $\sigma^2 < \frac{27 A^2-\sqrt{A+B} (9 A+9 B+4)^{3/2}+54 A B+18 A+27 B^2+18 B+2}{2 (2 A+2 B+1)}$, where the RHS can be shown to be strictly positive for any $A, B > 0$.

Comment: One can also treat $h(\theta)$ as a first order differential equation of $F$ with respect to $\theta$, solve it, and see that the solution for $F$ cannot be a proper CDF. This just verifies that one needs some special conditions on the parameters of $F$ in order fot $h(\theta)=0$ to hold, i.e. it validates the non-triviality of the exercise.